# Adding Subsequent Cell Values For Each Row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, cells

I'm new to excel so this might be a simple question. I have around 100 rows with 7 columns. Out of those, 4 column needs to have the value computed by 3rd and 2nd columns' value of the same row.

I know that this can be done using =C1*B1 and then copy paste this value to the next column. But I don't this is the easiest way. So please help me out with this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I did not understand you question very well but try to convert your formula to this  - $C1*$B1 and expand the formula to the needed columns and rows.

For copying the formula to other cells - highlight the last row and grab bottom corner to drag and extend to the next row or column.

Please refer to this tutorial for more information - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to avoid doing this drag and drop. I want to create an expression to automatically add these consecutive cell values

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I want to set this expression for the entire column, once

Comment: I think this will help you - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/apply-existing-formula-to-a-new-row-automatically/af6594d1-1b5a-4dbc-8123-5f11d219d268